# Oracle hash data across rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose I have an oracle table with two columns: type varchar2 and data varchar2. I want to know if there is a somewhat efficient way in plsql or straight oracle sql to compute a hash over all the data column (ideally sha1, but md5 or custom oracle hash functions are acceptable). For example, a mysql implementation of the solution might look like:

```
mysql dialect query:
select type, sha1(group_concat(data order by data separator '')) data_hash from my_table group by type

example output:    
+------+------------------------------------------+
| type | data_hash                                |
+------+------------------------------------------+
| a    | dbe343bfc23545c72f11fc7d2433df3263a71d0d |
| b    | b2baee034a7ed3aa1fa1bd441e141909f1b2f57c |
+------+------------------------------------------+
```

I'd prefer a straight query over a cursor iteration, and sha1 over other hashes.

Comment: Eh? rows can't have different types - I think you've confused rows and columns.

Comment: i meant to say columns, let me fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT type, SUM(ORA_HASH(data)) FROM my_table GROUP BY type
```

Oracle does have a COLLECT but that doesn't work with ORA_HASH. In 11g you can do

```
select deptno, ora_hash(listagg(ename) within group (order by ename))
from emp
group by deptno
```

Comment: If you want sha1, look at dbms_crypto (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm).

Comment: Why does SUM do in the context of SUM(ORA_HASH(data))? I thought sum was for base10 arithmetic.... not combining hashes?

Comment: ORA_HASH returns a number not a hex-style VARCHAR2. If you are not concerned about the ordering of hashes then a SUM is a simple way to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer for getMD5 function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897438/md5-in-oracle-dbms-obfuscation-toolkit-md5).  Also look into [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm) as others mentioned, this uses the older obfuscation toolkit, but the approach is the same.

To do your updates, something like:

```
update my_table
set my_hash = getMD5(col1 || col2 || col3);
```

Comment: That doesn't help to get the hash of all the data in the consolidation series (but I didn't downvote since you provided some useful links :)